# How to hide text between multiple <> // [] **

Tags: php

I use this code and all is ok, it hide text from `$comments` contains between `[]`, but i want to hide text from other symbols for. ex. `** && ^^ $$ ## // <>`. What i need to add here, to have INSTEAD OF

```
Date <20.02.2013> Time [11-00] Name #John#
```

Have this:

```
Date Time Name
```

?

```
function replaceTags($startPoint, $endPoint, $newText, $source) {
    return preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')#si', '$1'.$newText.'$3', $source);
}

$source= $comments;
$startPoint='[';
$endPoint=']';
$newText='';
echo replaceTags($startPoint, $endPoint, $newText, $source);
```

Comment: You forgot to add `'#'` as the second parameter to `preg_quote()`.

Comment: I'm curious to know what's the result of `"[xxx] and [yyy]"` with your current code ;-)

Comment: Current code just not display all between [] But i want to have the same with other symbols <>**$$##//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change

```
$startPoint='[';
$endPoint=']';
```

to

```
$startPoint='<';
$endPoint='>';
```

To do multiple symbols you can do multiple calls to the function, like this:

```
$source= $comments;
$newText='';

$str = replaceTags('[', ']', $newText, $source);
$str = replaceTags('<', '>', $newText, $str);
$str = replaceTags('*', '*', $newText, $str);
$str = replaceTags('&', '&', $newText, $str);
$str = replaceTags('^', '^', $newText, $str);
$str = replaceTags('$', '$', $newText, $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\#[^#]+#)/","",$str);
$str = replaceTags('/', '/', $newText, $str);

// add more here
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thx, but instead i start see all text with [ ]     I want to hide all text contains between ALL <> // ## ** []

Comment: Have a look at my revised answer

Comment: Thx it almost works except '#' -it hide ALL :(  and how to hide the symbols <>//@@##$$%%^^&&** too ?

Comment: You just keep adding more calls where I commented '//add more here'

Comment: Try this and see if it works $str = preg_replace("/\#[^#]+\#/","",$str);

Comment: Thx, Yes it works ! It remowed ## And text between. Now how to remove <>//@@$$%%^^&&**() tags too? Because for now i have this symbols without text <>??@@$$%%^^&&**()[]

Comment: Well you would do the same thing but replace the # with another symbol. like $str = preg_replace("/\&[^&]+&)/","",$str);

Comment: Im glad it all works. Could you please vote my answer and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create patterns for each pair:

```
$pairs = array(
  '*' => '*',
  '&' => '&',
  '^' => '^',
  '$' => '$',
  '#' => '#',
  '/' => '/',
  '[' => ']', // this
  '<' => '>', // and this pairs differently from the rest
);

$patterns = array();

foreach ($pairs as $start => $end) {
  $start = preg_quote($start, '/');
  $end = preg_quote($end, '/');

  $patterns[] = "/($start)[^$end]*($end)/";
}

echo preg_replace($patterns, '', $s), PHP_EOL;
//  not sure what you want here
//  echo preg_replace($patterns, '$1' . $newText . '$2', $s), PHP_EOL;
```